# Can't get Juice UI to work - Set up?

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

Am having trouble getting Juice UI to do anything. So, I created a seperate website, with just one page and still having trouble. Here is the markup for the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">        
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <juice:Datepicker ID="datepicker1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" runat="server" />

</asp:Content>
```

The date picker does not appear.

Only weird thing that happend on install (From NuGet) is that it tried to import a second copy of the .dll as 'JuiceUI.dll(2)'. I just deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add script references to the script manager before getting it to work. Something like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scripty" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```